Distinguishing two Gaussians
Assume we have two Gaussians $N_0 = \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_0)$ and $N_1 = \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma_1)$ where $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$ are two $n\times n$ covariance matrices.
What are the optimal test distinguishing them? If $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$ are both invertible, I know that Likelihood Ratio test works, i.e.
$$X^T (\Sigma_0^{-1} - \Sigma_1^{-1})X$$
has minimum testing error.
What if $\Sigma_0$ or $\Sigma_1$ are degenerate? As a guess, I feel like
$$X^T (\Sigma_0^{\dagger} - \Sigma_1^{\dagger})X$$
may work, where $\dagger$ denotes Moore–Penrose inverse.
My question is, is this true? And where can I find a good reference for distinguish Gaussians?

Possible duplicate Can I use Kolmogorov-Smirnov to compare two empirical distributions?

The way the question is written seems to mix up true (hypothesised) model parameters $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$, and their estimators, on which the likelihood ratio test is based. I wonder whether in the later parts you actually want to know what happens if the covariance matrix estimators of $\Sigma_0,\Sigma_1$ are degenerate, rather than the hypothesised true underlying matrices?

@ChristianHennig Hi Christian, in this problem, I meant only model parameters. So, there is no estimators of $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$. We know the true $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$.

What do you mean by "distinguishing them" then? You are assuming that you know everything already!?

@ChristianHennig I assume that under $H_0$, $X$ is generated from $N_0$ and under $H_1$ it is generated from $N_1$. After seeing data $X$, I want to tell from which distribution it is generated from.

Two possibilities:

the two variance matrices have zero variation on exactly the same subspace. In this case, there will be no variation in $X$ in this direction under either hypothesis. Project everything orthogonal to this subspace to get non-degenerate distributions

the two variance matrices don't have zero variation on the same subspace. In that case, one of the distributions has zero projection onto a subspace $S$ that the other distribution has non-zero projection on to. With probability 1, the projection on to $S$ will be zero for one of the distributions and non-zero for the other, giving a perfect test.


That is, suppose $X$ is two-dimensional and $\Sigma_1$ has variation only in the $x_2$ direction. If $\Sigma_2$ also has variation only in the $x_2$ direction just drop $x_1$ and work with two non-degenerate univariate Gaussians.
If $\Sigma_2$ does not have variation only in the $x_2$ direction, then you can tell which hypothesis is true by looking at the $x_1$ component of $X$: it will be exactly zero under hypothesis 1 and non-zero under hypothesis 2.

The way the question is written seems to mix up true (hypothesised) model parameters $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$, and their estimators, on which the likelihood ratio test is based. It may be worth mentioning that under the normal model assumption your second possibility regarding the estimators can only happen if in fact $\Sigma_0\neq\Sigma_1$ if there are more observations than dimensions (otherwise it has probability 0). If however there are fewer observations, this case will routinely happen even if in fact $\Sigma_0=\Sigma_1$ (and potentially of full rank).

I was assuming that when the question talked about two known $\Sigma$ matrices that was actually what they meant. But in the known-$\Sigma$ case, even a single observation will generically have a non-zero projection on to any prespecified direction (eg, a random point in a three-d Gaussian will have a non-zero x coordinate)
